# Where can I ask about image sensor architecture?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am wondering where could I ask about the architecture of specific types of image sensors used in specific devices?

Additionally, would the same site be able to provide information about how to read (and analyse) data from an excised image sensor?

I do not intend it to be a 'shopping list' and most definitely not a 'product recommendation'.  I am leaning towards Electrical Engineering; however, as there is a data collection and analysis side of things, maybe Computer Science or a similar site.  Or should I split it into two separate questions?

Comment: IMHO, you _should_ split it into _two or more_ separate questions.

Comment: @Mauricio yes I am thinking that way too - but where to post the 2 questions?

Comment: Depends on how you actually ask/phrase the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestions:

- for the hardware aspects of sensor devices: [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- for the data analysis part: [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

(Caveat: I don't participate on either of these sites.)